# Has your mother waked up yet?

Tags: present-perfect, irregular-forms

> *Has your mother waked up yet?*
>
> *Has your mother woken up yet?*

Are they the same meaning?
When do we use it?

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221905/past-tense-of-wake-is-there-a-difference-between-waked-and-woke.

Comment: Personally, I think the more appropriate sentence would be "Has your mother awoken?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English, the word "waked" is not regularly used.

I believe that it's used regionally in some parts of the US but the predominantly preferred version is "woken", as in your second example.

> *Has your mother woken up yet?*

Answer (score 2):

Not only in the US but, I think, all over the world, "woken up" would be considered "Standard" and, therefore correct."Waked" may sometimes be used in some regional dialects but would usually be considered to be incorrect by most speakers of English.